# How to write from .data file to .txt file In Java?

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I have written some information into a `.data` file

```
PrintWriter out;
DataOutputStream binaryFile= null;
public WriteToFile(String file,String text ) throws IOException {

     binaryFile= new DataOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(file,true));
     binaryFile.writeInt(2); 
     binaryFile.writeDouble(3);
     binaryFile.writeChar(2);
     binaryFile.writeUTF(text);
     binaryFile.close();  
}
```

I'm looking for a way to make a function that takes a `.data` file and writes each and every value into a corresponding text file

So Far I've tried this :

```
public void writeToTextFile(String myFile)
{
    DataOutputStream fichIn = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(myFile));;
    try {
        //How to take information from .data file and writethem in text file ? 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }

    // Some Code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read your binary file with a `DataInputStream` and the `readXXX()` methods corresponding to the `writeXXX()` methods you used to write it, and then use the methods of `PrintWriter` to write to the new text file.

Comment: Thanks for you Answer EJP , is it possible to refer a link?

Comment: You should start with the Javadoc, and you shouldn't have to be told that.